# Switching between two images

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple code

```
<a title="disable music" id="mute_link" name="mute_link"
    style="position:absolute;right:15px;top:15px;cursor:pointer;">
  <img src="images/icons/stopmusic.png"
       alt="stop playing music"
       name="music"
       onclick="document.images['music'].src='images/icons/stopmusicdis.png'">
</a>
```

And I have a problem with this. I need image will change after each click, it means I open site and i have there image stopmusic.png. After click on it I need to appear stopmusicdis.png. After second click on image I need back the stopmusic.png. It´s possible to do it?

Comment: U want output should be only in javascript or jquery is also k?

Comment: Can you send me the code? I think, I'm lamer in JS/jQuery so I can´t help myselft with this problem. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your javascript:

```
document.getElementById("mute_link").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var e = document.getElementsByName("music")[0];
    e.src = e.src.indexOf("stopmusic.png") == -1 ? 
            "images/icons/stopmusic.png":"images/icons/stopmusicdis.png"
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... This is definitely functional

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gerenal solution. You just have to change data-imgon and data-imgoff.

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Z4E5/

**HTML:**

```
<a title="disable music" id="mute_link" name="mute_link">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-imgon="http://placehold.it/350x150" data-imgoff="http://placehold.it/150x350" alt="stop playing music" name="music" id="music"/>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mute_link{position:absolute;right:15px;top:15px;cursor:pointer;}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("#mute_link").on("click", function () {

        if ($("#music").data("imgon") === $("#music").attr("src")) {
            //Change to OFF
            $("#music").attr("src", $("#music").data("imgoff"));
        } else {
            //Change to on
            $("#music").attr("src", $("#music").data("imgon"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you the idea.Use jquery or javascript

- Add click event for each image.
- inside click event for first image,change the image to second image
- Inside click event for second image,change the image to first image

Hope you understand this

example:
**html:**

```
 <div id="img"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#img").click(function(){
  if($("img").attr('src')=="image1.jpg"){
    $("img").attr('src','image2.jpg');
  }
  else
  {
    $("img").attr('src','image1.jpg'); 
  }     
});
```

this is just an example.

Comment: Can you send me the code? I think, I'm lamer in JS/jQuery so I can´t help myselft with this problem. Thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

create a JavaScript function and call it from the onclick event

```
<img src="images/icons/stopmusic.png" alt="stop playing music" name="music" onclick="change_img()"
```

Here is the function you could use :

```
<script>
    function change_img(){
        if (document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("name") == "img1"){
            document.getElementById("img").src = "new url"
            document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("name", "img2")
        }else {
            document.getElementById("img").src = "old url"
            document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("name", "img1")
        }
    }
</script>
```

It changes to the other image and back

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle with some javascript http://jsfiddle.net/gc9sW/

Find your `<img>` tag through `element.getElementById("id")`, then check its `src` attribute, and swap it around o/